# How to render Django CharField?

Tags: django

I have a list of dynamically created Charfields in a form but I can't figure out how to render the actual input (in this case a textarea).

This is the (simplified) loop:

```
{% for field in form.implementation_fields %}
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        {{ field.label }}
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

{{ field.label }} works fine, but {{ field }} just prints: django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x104e7fb50

EDIT: this is how the fields are created

```
    for index, implementation_field in enumerate(ImplementationField.objects.filter(report=report)):
        label = "Genomförning %s" % (index + 1)
        field = CharField(widget=Textarea(),
             label=label, initial=implementation_field.value, required=False)
        field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control implementation_field'})
        field_name = "implementation_value_" + str(index)
        self.implementation_fields.append(field)
        self.fields[field_name] = field
```

Comment: You need to post the code of the form and the view. What is `implementation_fields`? How are you instantiating the form and passing it to the template?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's the point of `implementation_fields`? Why can't you just iterate over the form itself, which is what you are supposed to do: `for field in form`?

Comment: It's a very complex form and the normal iteration is, more or less, not possible in this case. I figured this would be the easiest way of doing this, if I could just render the textarea.

Comment: But what's in `implementation_fields` isn't at all the same as what you get by iterating.